# How to update the style of all the items which are iterated using *ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

How do I apply style to all the items in the list which are iterated using `*ngFor` when clicked on a button which is outside the list.

```
<button (click)="markAllAsChecked();">Mark All as Checked</button>
<ion-list>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-item (click)="this.item.checked = !this.item.checked;">
      <div class="item" [ngStyle]="{background: item.checked ? 'green': 'red'}">
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

I wanted all the items background color to be turned to green when clicked on *Mark All as Checked* button.

I created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-r7uve7?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) using Stackblitz. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to iterate on each item and make `checked` to true.

```
markAllAsChecked(){
  this.items.forEach(item => item.checked = true);
}
```

and if you want to toggle background colour on same button then,

```
markAllAsChecked(){
      this.items.forEach(item => item.checked = !item.checked);
}
```

here is the working [link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6pvbea)

Comment: Thank you! I used `.map` instead of `forEach` for performance reasons. Here's what I did
`this.items.map(item => item.checked = true);`

Answer (score 0):

use `[ngClass]` instead of `[ngStyle]`

```
 <div class="item redBackgroundClass" [ngStyle]="{'greenBackgroundClass': item.checked}">
```

here keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed